# How to use a variable to construct a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following code:

```
temphash = {}
temphash[:ScenarioCnt] = scn_Cnt
temphash[:ScenarioNbr] = scn_Num
for i in 0..$event_Action_cnt
  temphash[:variablename] = value
  p temphash
end
$cash_File.write(JSON.pretty_generate(temphash))
```

In the `for` loop I want to replace the key name with a variable name. If I use:

```
temphash[:variablename] = value
```

Then it prints:

```
{"variablename": value}
```

I want the value of the variable to the replaced with the variable name.

Please let me know how this could be done.

Comment: Get in the habit of maintaining correct indentation. Your future self will thank you. Also, it helps us read and understand your code when trying to help you. The quicker we can do that the faster we can get to work on a solution and move on to help others.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" along with its linked pages, and "[mcve]". Your question isn't clearly asked. Perhaps an example of your expected output would help? Also, your code needs help; We use snake_case for variable names, not a mix of snake_case and camelCase. Don't use `$` (globals) unless you understand why you shouldn't use them; They're a weak bandage for a poor understanding of variable scoping. `for` loops are frowned upon because they leak the intermediate variable; Instead use `event_action_cnt.times`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments appreciate it. I am not sure I understand all of it but will try to understand it. I am from a legacy background so it will take some time.

Comment: Ruby's built-in IRB, or the PRY gem can help a lot as they make it easy to experiment and see how Ruby works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear but it sounds like you're asking how to turn a variable into a symbol to be used as the key of a hash key/value pair:

```
foo = {}
key = 'fred'
foo[key.to_sym] = 'wilma'
foo # => {:fred=>"wilma"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response yes this worked.